# Excel VBA, if a cell in a column contains anything, then change cell in that row to specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I don't really know VBA, but am I able to string together some stuff from googling, so apologies if this is easy or answered elsewhere, I was unable to find it

I am trying to make a macro for a file that has a variable number of rows. Basically, if a cell has any contents in column C, then I want the corresponding cells in Column D, E, and F to say "1", "2", and "3", respectively.

I have found some examples of people doing similar for specific text or numbers, but can't figure out how to do it if the cell contains anything, which will always be a positive number.

[image: example of spreadsheet]

Comment: You can do this with a formula. Do you really need VBA?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes I do need VBA, at least I think. This is being created so someone else can fairly frequently format a file for upload. I know how to create the formula to do this non-VBA, but the other person wouldn't be unable to.

Comment: You can write a formula with VBA.

Comment: I know so little VBA that I didn't realize that. I'll look into that.

Comment: If you have found similar examples, but don't know how to test if a cell (say `A1`) contains anything, you could use `if range("A1") <> ""`. If you want to treat cells which contain only white spaces as blank cells, you can `trim` it first, `if trim(range("A1")) <> ""`.